# Most general unifier - "infinite loop" - failure?

Tags: logic, unification

Lets say I have the following expressions where $x,y$ are both variables:

$p(x,y)$

$p(y,x)$

Is there a most general unifier in this case? since $x,y$ are both variables do I get stuck in an infinite loop while trying to run the basic MGU algorithm?

Comment: The MGU algorithm that I learned starts with the desired equation $p(x,y)=p(y,x)$, and first adjoins the required equations between the arguments, i.e., $x=y$ and $y=x$. Then, having the equation $x=y$, it removes $x$ from its vocabulary, removes the equation $x=y$, and replaces $x$ with $y$ in the remaining equations. So now it has $p(y,y)=p(y,y)$ and $y=y$. Then there's some cleaning up, but you already se the MGU: convert $x$ to $y$ to get unified $p(y,y)$. If you re-order the equations, you might end up with converting $y$ to $x$ and getting $p(x,x)$, but (continued in next comment)

Comment: (continuation of previous comment) that's OK, since MGU's are  only defined up to renaming anyway. The only way I see to get an infinite loop is to try to execute both versions of the algorithm in parallel --- converting $x$ to $y$ and also converting $y$ to $x$. Don't do that; execute the algorithm one step at a time.

Comment: @AndreasBlass - I guess you should write your comment as an answer, so that it can be accepted.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Done; thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested, transcribing my comments to an answer:

The MGU algorithm that I learned starts with the desired equation $(,)=(,)$, and first adjoins the required equations between the arguments, i.e., $=$ and $=$. Then, having the equation $=$, it removes $$ from its vocabulary, removes the equation $=$, and replaces $$ with $$ in the remaining equations. So now it has $(,)=(,)$ and $=$. Then there's some cleaning up, but you already see the MGU: convert $$ to $$ to get unified $(,)$. If you re-order the equations, you might end up converting $$ to $$ and getting $(,)$, but that's OK, since MGU's are only defined up to renaming anyway. The only way I see to get an infinite loop is to try to execute both versions of the algorithm in parallel --- converting $$ to $$ and also converting $$ to $$. Don't do that; execute the algorithm one step at a time.